# choose.files() defaulting to last directory used

Tags: r

According to the documentation for the choose.files function:

> choose.files(default = "", caption = "Select files",
>                multi = TRUE, filters = Filters,
>                index = nrow(Filters))
>
> If you would like to display files in a particular directory, give a
>   fully qualified file mask (e.g., "c:\*.*") in the default argument.
>   If a directory is not given, the dialog will start in the current
>   directory the first time, and remember the last directory used on
>   subsequent invocations.

My code is as follows:

```
AZPic = choose.files(default = "", caption = "Select Azimuth Picture", multi = FALSE, filters = Filters[c("All","jpeg"),])
STSPic = choose.files(default = "", caption = "Select Side to Side Elevation Picture", multi = FALSE, filters = Filters[c("All","jpeg"),])
FTBPic = choose.files(default = "", caption = "Select Front to Back Elevation Picture", multi = FALSE, filters = Filters[c("All","jpeg"),])
OrientationPic = choose.files(default = "", caption = "Select Orientation Picture", filters = Filters[c("All","jpeg"),])
```

Now when I run this code, it defaults to my home directory for all 4 calls. 
It starts there for the first call of course, but afterwards should it not remember the folder I navigate to?
I typically will hop through another 3 or 4 folders to find the pictures for the job, but all of them for each program use will be in the same folder.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running this? RStudio? The base R GUI? What R version? One line of code at a time?

Comment: Rstudio, R version 3.3.
Running it in a larger code, later using those variables to insert into a powerpoint.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. `choose.files` remembers the directory for me. Tested with `R_3.5.0` and `RStuido_1.1.383` on Windows 10.

Comment: Interesting. That means it must be something local to my machine then presumably.